# Can I modify an attribute by passing it as variable to a method? - python

Tags: python, class, methods, attributes

So I have a class with an attribute, say a, and I want to be able to modify it by using a method but I want that method to be reusable with other attributes.

Example:

```
class My_Class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
    def add_one(self, x):
        x = x + 1
    def add_to_all(self):
        self.add_one(self.a)
        self.add_one(self.b)
```

with the code above I would expect:

```
adder = My_Class()
print(adder.a)

# 0

adder.add_to_all()

print(adder.a)
#1
```

this is not working and I am wondering how can do what I intend.

ChaGPT suggests:

```
class My_Class():
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
        self.b = 1
    def add_one(self, x):
        setattr(self, x, getattr(self, x) + 1)
    def add_two(self):
        self.add_one('a')
        self.add_one('b')
```

which works, but I might as well create two methods:

```
    def add_a(self):
        self.a = self.a + 1
    
    def add_b(self):
        self.b = self.b + 1
```

and would duplicate code but in my opinion it would be cleaner (this case only adds 1 to a variable but in my real problem there are many variables and complex operations in each method, a and b).

Any idea if there is another way to implement this or sugestion of which option to use (chatGPT or duplicate methods)?

Comment: It sounds like you just need a top-level function which takes 1 or more parameters and `return`s a value. That would be the most reuseable and testable way of doing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, `int`s are immutable. When you run `x += 1`, Python doesn't modify the value in memory that `x` is pointing to—it just points `x` to a different value.

With that in mind, there are a couple of ways you can go about this implementation. The solution you got from ChatGPT is probably the most straightforward, but here's another way that works:

```py
class My_Class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = [0, 1]

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.values[0]

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self.values[1]

    def add_to_all(self):
        self.values = [val + 1 for val in self.values]
```

This also will accomplish what you're going for, although if you also want to be able to set the values for a & b (i.e. `self.a = 3`) you'll need to add [setter methods](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/property/setter.html) as well.